# How to choose Google App Engine servers' location

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

In this doc https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/location it is said I can set the servers hosting my google app engine based web application in EU but I can't find the show advanced options button when creating a new GAE application. Is it still possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its definitely possible with new console at console.developers.google.com.

[image]

Comment: it is not shown in the appengine dashboard but it is in  he console.developers.google.com. Is there any way to check (only check) what data center (EU vs. US) is used to serve an already created ap?

Comment: The easiest way is probably `import os; print os.environ.get('DATACENTER')`

Comment: I think I have seen data center locations column on the list of projects.. I wonder if Google removed the column or my memory is wrong.

Comment: the column location is still available on [appengine.google.com](https://appengine.google.com/). It is not currently available on [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: now there are 3 options:

europe-west
us-central
us-east1