# How to select Google App Engine Location

Tags: google-app-engine

GAE recently got some updates including "organisations" which seems to have also resetted many other settings - e.g. super unclean migration.

Question: how can I select the deploy region/location for google-app-engine apps?

Unfortunately it is not anymore possible to do so as described here: [How to choose Google App Engine servers' location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700315/how-to-choose-google-app-engine-servers-location)

When I create a new project there is no "advanced" settings. If I still just "blindly" deploy (after ignoring the annoying new tutorial / quick start that is forced into ones throat) it will use europe-west as region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Google Cloud Console -> Menu -> Compute -> App Engine

You should then see a box with title "Your first app", follow the steps and at some point it will prompt you to select the server location (cannot be changed later once selected). After selecting server location you don't need to continue with the Hello World app, just deploy your code as normal.

I believed something has been changed recently and there's no clear documentation yet.